# What is the type of a SID that is neither RNAV nor RNP?

Tags: faa-regulations, ifr-navigation, departure-sid

I am studying FAA's Order 8260.46F and I have noticed that, as far as the different types of SIDs are concerned, it states:

> **[3-5]** (1) “RNAV 1” will be the default designation for RNAV DPs. Annotate procedures with a standard note: “RNAV 1” on Form 8260-15B [see appendix E].
>   (2) “RNP 1” (in-lieu-of RNAV 1) will be used when a DP that contains an RF leg or when surveillance (Radar) monitoring is not desired for when DME/DME/IRU will be used. Annotate the procedure with a standard note: “RNP 1” on Form 8260-15B [see appendix E].
>   (3) All RNAV DPs will contain a note that describes the equipment sensor limitations.

However, I have trouble figuring out what type of SID is the [La Guardia Five Departure](http://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1808/00289laguardia.pdf#nameddest=(LGA)) ( [route description](http://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1808/00289laguardia_c.pdf#nameddest=(LGA)) and [take-off minimums](http://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1808/00289laguardia_c2.pdf#nameddest=(LGA)) ) of *La Guardia* airport. It is does not have the indication "RNAV" and, as far as I can tell, it is not an RNP departure procedure either.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: That SID uses conventional NAVAIDs- the additional pages have the textual description of the route.

Comment: @sbooth thank you for your comment. Could you help me a bit more to clarify this? When you say that it uses conventional NAVAIDs, does this mean it is an RNAV type of SID? If not, then how would you call this type of SID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That SID is not an RNAV SID since it uses VOR/DME and headings for navigation. The FAA Aeronautical Chart User’s Guide simply refers to them as “non-RNAV SID’s”